# Best noSQL database for below concept

Tags: c++, database

I have a conflict to decide which database to be selected for the following criteria

1. Need to Store data as per aggregation.
2. Both ascending and descending sorting should be available on integer/float values.
3. Faster reading and writing.
4. C++ coding should be supported.

For Example I have a string1 to be stored in the database if same is to be inserted again in the database simply it should increment it is count. And at the ascending/descending sorting should be done on the whole data so that while fetching the data I can present it as the sorting applied.

Comment: mongoDB, redis? also, plain SQL will do it, if (3) isn't a high priority.

Comment: mongodb upserts would work, and there is a pretty simple C++ api